# Authorize Object using spring security?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security, spring-security-acl

I have an application that have two domain model 
Organization and TicketQuestion .
Authenticated User want to create ticket that have  an organization property to solve that
each user permit to some organization like this:

User1 permit to  Organization1

User2 permit to  Organization2

TicketController.java have  save method that create ticket.
I have this vulnerability: User1 can invoke method with ticket that have   Organization2( that dose not have permission to it ).
I am using  Hibernate filter for authorize data in GET methods but i dont know how can i protect data that user want persist and  dose not have permission ??;

```
/ticket/save  

{
   id:-1,
   organization:{
    id:2,
    title:'organization2' //not allowed this organization
   }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "core_organization_structure")
public class OrganizationStructure {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "core_Ticket")
public class Ticket  {


    ..some prop

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "org_id", nullable = false)
    private OrganizationStructure org;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the form is submitted, you need to load the authenticated user's permissions and check that they are authorized to perform the action they are attempting to perform.

If the user is attempting to create a ticket for an organization that they do not have permissions to; don't persist the record, and handle it appropriately. (Throw an exception, return a 401, etc...)

Comment: yes one of basic solution is that . imagine i have Domain model that have 10 property that all have this problem .i write code for load for each property  ?!  another problem :i have add update and delete method and maybe have more than this 3 method, another problem is that if organization used in 100 domain model write this check code 100 time  , i want do solve problem in outside of my service .